# Why won't Ruby return an array without "return"?

Tags: ruby

```
def foo
  1,2
end
```

causes syntax error "unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end"

I'd think this is valid Ruby. What's wrong?

Comment: "I'd think this is valid Ruby. What's wrong?" – It's not.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's quite obvious! I'm looking for reasoning.
`return 1,2` works. Going by Ruby convention of omitting return, I'd think just `1,2` would work.

Comment: @slowpoison there is a specific rules in Ruby's syntax for `return` followed by a comma separated list to return an array. Similarly if you have an assignment with a single variable on the left hand side (or a `*` variable) then this can assign an array too e.g. `x = 1, 2`. But there isn't a general syntax to make an array without the square brackets.

Answer (score 6):

You're not returning an array.

You should have this:

```
def foo
  [1, 2]
end
```

Ruby isn't expecting a comma (,) because it isn't valid syntax.  Integers in a simple array should be surrounded by brackets as well as delineated by a comma.

Answer (score 5):

If you used *explicit* return it will work.

```
def foo
  return 1,2
end
```

But that wouldn't work with *implicit* return. To make it work with implicit return you need to give it `[1, 2]`.

Comment: I mentioned "without 'return'", so I knew that return works. I'm wondering why the difference.

Comment: @slowpoison That's how parser is written by Matz. :) I don't know the history behind this too, as I really never needed.